# Entity framework search optimization (Enumerable.where(c => c.collection.any(condition)))

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, entity

I am having hard time solving this, 
I have Member object which has a lot of relations, 2 of them are coming from the same table, but one is seller one is buyer

```
public partial class Member {
//a lot of properties, then the one i am using for my search

public virtual ICollection<Trade> Trades1 { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Trade> Trades2 { get; set; }
}
```

the linq i am using

```
members = context.Members.AsNoTracking().Include(x => x.Trades1).Include(x => x.Trades2)
            .Where(x => x.MemberStatus != StatusTypeRef.MemberStatus.ClosedAccount &&                           
                  (x.Trades1.Any(d => d.Date >= startDate && 
                  d.Date <= EndDate && 
                  d.Status== "Completed" && 
                  d.BuyAmount >0)
                  ||
                  x.Trades2.Any(d => d.Date >= StartDate && 
                  d.Date <= EndDate && d.Status =="Completed" &&
                  d.SellAmount > 0)));
```

This is taking so long to process, also note that Trade table have a lot of data, is it the issue ? 
How can this be optimized, it is really slow.

I tried to get trades first then cast all member ids to a list and use it to search all members, that was slower. 
Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: A few things could be causing it... it could be the way indexes are set up (or not set up). Usually what I do in these situations is take the SQL generated by the entity framework and review it. Also, you shouldn't need to use the Include() method there... if trades are generated by EF correctly you should be able to access it directly in your where method.

Comment: Thanks Cory, I will remove Include and test, I didn't know that I can use the condition without including, I removed the Include, I got the same result, with huge impact. Thanks a lot

Comment: Sweet. Outline what you changed in an answer to help others that come along after you.

Comment: I will wait a bit for more answers, I will discuss with colleagues also, then I will post an answer with the best solution I found.

Comment: FWIW, you should change the names of your properties to something like `TradesAsBuyer` and `TradesAsSeller`. `Trades1` and `Trades2` is a recipe for disaster, as I can guarantee some one at some point is going to switch those up.

Comment: @ChrisPratt It is auto generated, can i change the names ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Searching there was nothing to be done except removing all the `Includes` that I didn't need.